# How to show Arabic text in notification?

Tags: swift, swift3, push-notification

I am getting FCM push notification in both languages English/Arabic but I want to show it only in Arabic, How to show this?

My Code-

```
@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
        if let jsonResult = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {

            if let notifyType = jsonResult["type"] as? String {

                if notifyType == "8" ||  notifyType == "18" {
                    self.pushRedirection(userInfo: userInfo)

                }else{

                    if let league_id = jsonResult["league_id"] as? String {

                        if let contestUnique_id = jsonResult["contest_unique_id"] as? String {

                        }
                    }
                }                    
            }
        }        
        completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}
```

I am getting this notification in English(Match Reminder). How to set this in Arabic

[image]

**My notification data is -**

```
[AnyHashable("gcm.notification.type"): 5, AnyHashable("league_id"): 3, AnyHashable("en_msg"): Match Reminder, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.ar_msg"): القوانين, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.en_msg"): Match Reminder, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.league_id"): 3, AnyHashable("contest_unique_id"): KBm8oVuTR, AnyHashable("gcm.message_id"): 0:1528974245362555%6c5fd9d06c5fd9d0, AnyHashable("gcm.notification.contest_unique_id"): KBm8oVuTR, AnyHashable("ar_msg"): القوانين, AnyHashable("google.c.a.e"): 1, AnyHashable("type"): 5, AnyHashable("aps"): {
    alert = "Match Reminder";
}, AnyHashable("body"): Match Reminder]
```

Comment: you have to explain what problem you're facing. What's your input and what's your current output that needs to be fixed?

Comment: Currently, I am unable to get, where is the title is setting, But its showing notification in English.

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Can you add an image to explain what you expect to get and compare it with what your result looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a [notification service extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension). That will allow you to modify the notification's payload prior to display.

As the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension) say:

> A UNNotificationServiceExtension object ... lets you customize the content of a remote notification before it is delivered to the user.

And that is exactly what you are wishing to do.

Comment: Can you please explain little bit more, by an example?

Comment: No, I'm not going to write your code for you. You asked how this could be done, and I believe I've told you. If the notification payload is arriving in English, there is only way to change it so that it appears to the user in Arabic, and that is through a notification service extension. End of story. Why not read the docs? Why not watch Apple's video on this topic (https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/708/)?

Comment: See my updated question, Ohk can you please help me boss to set up. And where to write code, Because when the notification came- didreceivenotification not called.

Comment: You write the code in the notification service extension. When you ask Xcode to make you a notification service extension, it gives you a new target with template code to get you started.

Comment: Okay Thanks for the day

Comment: I setup service extension, but it's not calling.