# How to return string value in completionHandler?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification

I have a **completionHandler** of type **UNNotificationPresentationOptions**, Now I want to return string value, instead of .alert.

I want to show Arabic text in my notification, So I want to set **msg** value in completionHandler

```
    @available(iOS 10, *)
    extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

        // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
        func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                    willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                    withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
            let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
            print(userInfo)

            let userInfoa = notification.request.content
            let sd = userInfoa.title

            if let jsonResult = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {


            var msg = ""
            if let aps_Data = userInfo as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
                if let ar_message = aps_Data["gcm.notification.body_ar"] {

                    print(ar_message)
                    msg = ar_message as! String

                }
            }
            let content:UNNotificationPresentationOptions = msg

            completionHandler([content])

          //completionHandler([.alert]) .  *I dont want use  .alert



        }

        }
    }
```

Comment: That seems to be a native delegate method. In which case if you change the completion handler, it will no longer respond. You might want to handle your alert where it is received.

Comment: Why do you want to return a string?

Comment: I want to show Notification in Arabic language, But by default its coming in English

Comment: you need to pre-localize it from the beginning , is it a push or local ??

Comment: Its Push notification, Can you suggest a better way to pre-Localize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look to declaration

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
public struct UNNotificationPresentationOptions : OptionSet {

   public init(rawValue: UInt)


  public static var badge: UNNotificationPresentationOptions { get }

  public static var sound: UNNotificationPresentationOptions { get }

  public static var alert: UNNotificationPresentationOptions { get }
}
```

these are types of permissions .alert /.sound/.badge , you can't change delegate method signature to what you want , it's main purpose is to return the permissions that system will trigger for this coming   notification

//

You can use notification service && content extension

[image]

Implement your edits here

```
override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {
    self.contentHandler = contentHandler
    bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

    if let bestAttemptContent = bestAttemptContent {
        // Modify the notification content here...
        bestAttemptContent.title = "\(bestAttemptContent.title) [modified]"

        contentHandler(bestAttemptContent)
    }
}
```

Comment: I added this alredy, But the class service extension not called.

Comment: Did you set **mutable-content = 1** in notification json  check this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-10-notification-service-extensions--cms-27550

Comment: If Not, The extension class will not called?

Comment: See my other question for better understanding- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857591/how-to-show-arabic-text-in-notification/50859263#50859263

Comment: I think this response is from firebase , if so try the native way usng php script with .pem certificate , then try with attached key anyway follow every step in tutorial

Comment: Yes, notification is from Firebase, which tutorial exactly?

Comment: attached above link in comment

Comment: Also this https://makeapppie.com/2017/01/24/using-user-notifications-service-extensions-in/

Comment: Okay Thanks, I will implement from one of the tutorials.

Comment: Still not called Service Extension class?